# Applying for a Super visa without immigration consultant or lawyer

Tags: visa, canada, resident-permit, dependent-visa

I would like to apply for a super visa for my mother back at home but I don't have any siblings back at home and my mother is alone. She does have a brother and a sister who live close by. I am hesitant apply on my own thinking about the fact whether not having children or husband back at home can hurt her chances of getting the super visa. Has anyone faced similar situations where the application was still successful? Also would going through an immigration agent or lawyer increase the chances?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are two questions here. The first needs more detail, the second is opinion-based. I voted to close.